# Network user access issue while creating GCP AI Platform Notebook instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to create a AI platform notebook instance in a project that has a shared VPC and subnets.
I am using a non default service account - gave it network user access. Also gave network user access to the notebook default service account, i.e service-<project_number>@gcp-sa-notebooks.iam.gserviceaccount.com

I am creating a customized instance with c2 machine. The instance is not geting created and I am getting the following error:

`Required 'compute.subnetworks.use' permission for '<subnet>'`

The service accounts already have network user role, which comprises of subnetworks.use permission. What might be the reason I am getting such an error?

I cannot use default compute engine SA

Comment: Seems to be you are passing the correct permissions, does the user which is creating the Notebook has Service Account User permission over the "non default service account". Does this user also has "compute.subnetworks.use" permissions?

Comment: @gogasca , yes the user has network user role, and also has the permission to use the service account

Comment: I would open a case, seems to be you have the right configuration in place.

Comment: @gogasca, I solved it yesterday. Turns out that we have to give network user access at the shared host project level specifically. I was providing the access at the dev project level itself. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

So what I observed is, we have to give network user access at the shared host project. Also, I had to give network user access to both the notebook default SA and custom SA.
This solved the issue for me